# Without the return statement for a method written in a class I was able to print the value of that function from outside the class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in python .
There is a class employee which has three function. One is the `__init__` function,fullname function  and other `apply_raise` function .The apply raise function does not take any arguments except for the instance variable(self) itself. Without using the return statement for this function  I was able to print the value of the function from outside the class. How is that possible?

```
def apply_raise(self):
        pay=int(self.pay*1.04)
        return pay ( its not re

class Employee:
    def __init__(self,first,second, pay):
        self.first = first
        self.second= second
        self.pay = pay
        self.email = first+"."+second + "@gmail.com"
    def fullname(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.first,self.second)
     def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay=int(self.pay*1.04)
Emp1 = Employee("Mercury","John",5000)
Emp2=  Employee("Abe","Jo",6000)
print(Emp1.pay)
Emp1.apply_raise()
print(Emp1.pay)

def apply_raise(self):
   pay=int(self.pay*1.04)  
   return pay                         //with return statement 
Emp1.apply_raise()
print(Emp1.pay)    ->The output is 5000


def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay=int(self.pay*1.04)       //without return statement

mp1.apply_raise()
print(Emp1.pay)    ->The output is 5200
```

Both output are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use your example to explain step by step. You have a class employee and you create an instance of this class, that is an object, like this:

```
emp1 = Employee("Mercury","John",5000)
```

This will call the constructor, which is the `__init__` function defined inside the class. The constructor is going to call it with the given parameters, that is

```
first = "Mercury"
second = "John"
pay = 5000
```

The constructor sets up the values of the object attributes: `first`, `second`, `pay` and `email`. So your current `emp1` has the following:

```
first = "Mercury"
second = "John"
pay = 5000
email = "Mercury.John@gmail.com"
```

The attributes and the methods (object functions) can be accessed using dot after your object, so if you want to see the value of `pay` you do it like this:

```
print(emp1.pay) # This shows 5000
```

You can also set the values of the attributes the same way:

```
emp1.first = "Luke"
```

Now if you want to show the `first` attribute:

```
print(emp1.first)  # This shows Luke
```

The value of `first` has been updated to `"Luke"`.

When you call `emp1.apply_raise()` in your code, you are actually calling the same function each time, which is the one defined in your class. To call the function defined outside the class, you need to call it like `apply_raise(emp1)`.

In `apply_raise` you are modifying the value of the attribute `pay`, by multiplying it by 1.04.

```
print(emp1.pay)     # shows 5000
emp1.apply_raise()  # modifies pay=5000*1.04
print(emp1.pay)     # shows 5200
```

The return statement is the value to which the function is going to evaluate to. If you specify no `return`, it evaluates to `None`, as it is the case for `apply_raise`.

```
print(emp1.apply_raise())  # shows None
```

But you can still access `pay` value, because it is not a local variable, it is an attribute since it is prefixed with `self`. It would be a different story if you would have defined the class method as following:

```
def apply_raise(self):
    pay = self.pay*1.04
```

Here we are creating a local variable called `pay`. This variable exists only in the context of the function. No modification is being done to the object's attribute `pay`. So if we try it out:

```
print(emp1.pay)     # shows 5000
emp1.apply_raise()  # defines pay=5000*1.04
print(emp1.pay)     # shows 5000
print(pay)          # error! not defined
```

But if you `return` the local variable `pay`, you could use this outside the context of the method:

```
def apply_raise(self):
    pay = self.pay*1.04
    return pay
```

You need to assign it to a variable:

```
print(emp1.pay)               # shows 5000
new_pay = emp1.apply_raise()  # returns pay=5000*1.04 and assigns it to new_pay
print(emp1.pay)               # shows 5000
print(new_pay)                    # 5002
```

You notice the attribute of `emp1` did not change, but we were able to use the `pay` local variable outside `apply_raise` by assigning it to `new_pay`, thanks to the `return` statement.

Hope it is clear enough. If you have more questions, do not hesitate!